# Frenet Equations And Unit Normal

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

By Frenet equation we have:
$$\dot{T}=\kappa N$$
But on the other hand $\dot{T}=N$, so the curvature is always $1$?

Comment: Explain why you think both of these equations hold.

Comment: Your second equation is not exactly true.  Remember that N is the derivative of T with respect to the arclength, divided by the length.

Comment: N equals the derivative of T with respect to the polar angle.

Answer (score 6):

No, $\dot{T}=N$ is not correct.  But it is true that $\dot{T}$ is the derivative of $T$ with respect to the arc-length parameter, which makes it perpendicular to $T$.  A unit vector in the same direction as $\dot{T}$ is called the "unit normal" $N$, and the magnitude of $\dot{T}$ is called the "curvature" $\kappa$.  So your other equation $\dot{T} = \kappa N$ is correct.  Unless $\dot{T} = \mathbf{0}$, and $N$ is not defined.

Comment: If we look at $t=(cos\alpha,sin\alpha)$ for example, so because it is in arc length my "claim" holds?

Comment: For $t=(\frac 12\cos(2\alpha),\frac 12 \sin(2\alpha))$ we have $\dot{T}=-2N\ne N$.